# How to get "title" with Jsoup html parser?

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I have code,which can extract text value of the class. But in this class, exist attribute "title", which I should get. While I can extract only class ".day__description". Below part my code.

```
try {

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
    Elements nodeDay = document.select(".day__description");
    if(nodeDay.size() > 0) {
        day = nodeDay.get(0).text();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    day = "Not found";
}
return null;  

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    txttitle.setText(day);

    }
```

I need to get "title" from this part of the site:

```
<div class="day__description" title="SomeText">...</div>
```

As a result in variable "day", should be text "Some Text". Sorry for my English))

I hope all understand. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements div=doc.select("div.day__description");
System.out.println(div.attr("title"));
```